# Why I get Expression 'undefined' error in my directive link function?

Tags: angularjs

Here the directive definition:

```
  (function () {
      "use strict";

    angular.module("damageEvent").directive("sitesDamage", ["damageEventServices", sitesDamage]);

    function sitesDamage(damageEventServices) {
        var directive = {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                sitesDamagesList:'=',
                region: "=",
                contractid: "=",
                frequencyid: "="
            },
            templateUrl: "app/damageEvent/templates/sitesDamage.tmpl.html",
            controller: "sitesDamageController",
            controllerAs: "list",
            link: function (scope, elem, attr) {
                return damageEventServices.getSitesDamages()
                    .then(function (result) {
                        scope.sitesDamagesList = result.data;
                    });
            }
        }

        return directive;
    }
})();
```

In link function in this row:

```
 scope.sitesDamagesList = result.data;
```

I get this error:

`Error: [$compile:nonassign] Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'sitesDamagesList' used with directive 'sitesDamage' is non-assignable!`

Any idea why I get this error?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are not passing required attributes when using directive.

```
<sitesDamage sitesDamagesList="something"></sitesDamage>
```

If your attributes are optional use `=?`

```
scope: {
   sitesDamagesList:'=?'
   ...
},
```

> Optional attributes should be marked as such with a question mark: `=?`
>   or `=?attr`. If the binding expression is non-assignable, or if the
>   attribute isn't optional and doesn't exist, an exception
>   ($compile:nonassign) will be thrown upon discovering changes to the
>   local value, since it will be impossible to sync them back to the
>   parent scope